# How do I insert a simple array into a database (php/MySQL)?

Tags: php

I'm working on a form in which the user makes a few selections, and then each selected item's name needs to go into a table in a db. The user's name can go with each item as an identifier for the user's selections. The number of selections, and the names of the selections will change but the two fields in the database remain constant. My problem is that on insert, I get an error that there is no column with the name specified in the VALUE I'm sending. Its tripped me all up....can't figure out why. Thanks a lot for any help or advice.

Full code:

```
<?php 

$db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('reflex') or die(mysql_error());

$name_array = array('harp1','harp2','harp3');

if (isset($_POST['interests'])) {

    $interests_str = implode(" ", $_POST['interests']);// converts $_POST interests into a string
    $interests_array = explode(" ", $interests_str);// converts the string to an array which you can easily manipulate  




            foreach ($name_array as $row=>$name)

            {

            $username = mysql_real_escape_string($name);

            $photo = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['interests'][$row]);

            mysql_query('INSERT INTO photos (username, photo) VALUES ("' . $username . '", ' . $photo . ')') or die(mysql_error());

            }




}



?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>array test</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="array.php" method="post">



    <input type="checkbox" name="interests[]" value="Politics" />Politics<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="interests[]" value="Entertainment" /><br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="interests[]" value="Tech" /><br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="interests[]" value="Health" /><br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="interests[]" value="Living" /><br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="interests[]" value="Travel" /><br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="interests[]" value="World" /><br />


    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is the structure of 'reflex' db and what fields are there in this user form?

Answer (score 0):

$photo is not surrounded by quotes in your SQL statement.  Also, the loop goes like this:

Loop 1: $username="harp1", $photo="[value of first selected checkbox]"

Loop 2: $username="harp2", $photo="[second value]"

Loop 3: $username="harp3", $photo="[third value]"

it doesn't make sense...

Comment: Also, the implode/explode isn't really needed. Is there a reason behind that?

Comment: Thanks for the replies! The form is in the code above below the php. I put $photos in double quotes and that gave me an error:

Comment: Thanks for the replies! I added double quotes to $photos and got errors: 
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /Users/harp/Sites/lw/reflex/array.php on line 24

Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in /Users/harp/Sites/lw/reflex/array.php on line 24

Database table is just two columns, no indexes etc, one is 'name' one is 'photo'.

Ideally the user will have just one name entered in (same name) the db with their selections from the form. The form code is below the php code above.

THanks!

Comment: Hard to say exactly, but the notices probably are coming in because you didn't select any checkboxes.  The photo value is getting the index of the selected checkboxes.  If none are selected, it will cause errors.  There's not entirely enough to go on to correct all of the problems in this code, but the quotes in the SQL should fix the insert.

Comment: Yes, you're right! WhenI clear out the page and then select a couple, it does in fact insert them. Awesome. I'll try and work out the rest on my own. Thanks so much, really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use double quoted strings to create database queries:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO photos (username, photo) VALUES ('$username', '$photo')")
    or die(mysql_error());
```

You forgot to put quotes around `$photo`. Double quoted strings reduce this kind of errors by making them easier to read.